# MySQL limiting within a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi so i have a database with the multiple tables with different records like so,

```
- table_1
    - student_name
    - student_id
    - id
    - note
    - ...

- table_2
    - id
    - leave
    - ...
```

leave currently contains the records of all the days the student has taken day off.

sample data for table_2 as requested

| id | leave | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 675 | 2011-05-04 | ... |
| 675 | 2012-04-15 | ... |
| 675 | 2021-06-23 | ... |
| 345 | 2019-10-14 | ... |
| 345 | 2011-04-05 | ... |
| 345 | 2019-02-13 | ... |

So my question is how do i LEFT JOIN the tables and return the last leave date for the student instead of fetching all the leave date's for that particular student.

here's the current output that i'm getting

| name | id | note | last absent | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 675 | good student | 2011-05-04 | ... |
| John Doe | 675 | good student | 2012-04-15 | ... |
| John Doe | 675 | good student | 2021-06-23 | ... |
| Jack Sparrow | 345 | average student | 2019-10-14 | ... |
| Jack Sparrow | 345 | average student | 2019-10-14 | ... |
| Jack Sparrow | 345 | average student | 2019-02-13 | ... |
| Ryan Reynolds | 567 | below average student | 2011-07-22 | ... |

Here is my expected output.

| name | id | note | last absent | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 675 | good student | 2021-06-23 | ... |
| Jack Sparrow | 345 | average student | 2019-10-14 | ... |
| Ryan Reynolds | 567 | below average student | 2011-07-22 | ... |

All help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding sample data of second table and desired result would be helpful.

Comment: Use an aggregate query to return the `MAX` (most recent) leave date

Comment: A [mcve] should include _both_ sample table data end the expected result.

Comment: first retrieve student_id wise absent/leave then join with main table with student_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin already commented, you need to use an [aggregate query](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx). Since dates are effectively ordered lexicographically, the most recent date in a set of dates is its maximum. Therefore, you need to use the MAX() aggregator. Since you want to get the most recent date per student, you need to group the query by student. And since MySQL usually does not want you to print columns that are not in the GROUP BY clause, you'll need to add all columns from TABLE_1 to that clause. This should do what you want:

```
SELECT TABLE_1.NAME, TABLE_1.ID, TABLE_1.NOTE, MAX(TABLE_2.LEAVEDATE) AS last_absent
FROM TABLE_1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_1.ID = TABLE_2.ID
GROUP BY TABLE_1.ID, TABLE_1.NAME, TABLE_1.NOTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Distinct table_1.Id, table_1.name,table_1.notes,MAX(table_2.leavedate) 
AS Latestleavedate 
FROM Employeedetails table_1 JOIN Leavedetails table_2 ON table_1.Id=table_2.Id 
GROUP BY table_1.Id, table_1.name,table_1.notes;
```

Here I have used the MAX function to get the latest leave details from the `table_2` and then I have grouped this by `Id, name, notes.`